# Check if the sum of features is greater than one

Tags: pyqgis

How can I check if the sum of 2 features is greater than 1? I used the following code but the last elif statement gives an error 'unsupported operand type for +: Qvariant and Qvariant'

```
with edit(layer):
        for feature in layer.getFeatures():
            context.setFeature(feature)
            if feature ["#woon"] == 1 and feature["#utiliteit"] == 0:
                feature['kW_gelijk'] = enkele_woon_aansluiting.evaluate(context)
            elif feature ["#woon"] == 0 and feature["#utiliteit"] == 1:
                feature['kW_gelijk'] = enkele_utiliteit_aansluiting.evaluate(context)
            elif feature ["#woon"] + feature ["#utiliteit"] > 1:
                feature['kW_gelijk'] = kW_gelijk.evaluate(context)
            else:
                None
            layer.updateFeature(feature)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to skip `NULL` values otherwise it raises this error.

```
with edit(layer):
    for feature in layer.getFeatures():

        # Skip features that have a null value in either field used
        if feature["#woon"] == NULL or feature["#utiliteit"] == NULL:
            continue

        context.setFeature(feature)
        if feature["#woon"] == 1 and feature["#utiliteit"] == 0:
            feature['kW_gelijk'] = enkele_woon_aansluiting.evaluate(context)
        elif feature ["#woon"] == 0 and feature["#utiliteit"] == 1:
            feature['kW_gelijk'] = enkele_utiliteit_aansluiting.evaluate(context)
        elif feature["#woon"] + feature["#utiliteit"] > 1:
            feature['kW_gelijk'] = kW_gelijk.evaluate(context)

        layer.updateFeature(feature)
```

PS: the `else: None` can be removed safely it has no impact